# Why is there plasma near the inlet when Voltage is increased to higher Voltage? What can I do to eliminate this?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, plasma-physics

[image]We built this plasma jet reactor with a side inlet of helium at 2 slm. My question is why is there plasma generated near the inlet where in it should only be at the bottom part. You can check the photos I attached here. We found out that increasing the voltage above 3kV will result to this plasma generated near the gas inlet. What can we do to fix this problem? We wanted to eliminate plasma formed at the inlet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuCgA.jpg)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think it should "only" appear near the outlet? You clearly have a path to ground through the inlet, whether you designed it that way or not, and once the field is large enough you will get the arc you see.

Comment: Hi Jon Custer, I was looking for a reply from you but i don't know if there is any private messaging here.  Is this a design flaw ?  We are thinking about tubing material, the tube at the left side of the insulation tape is different from the one attached to the quartz glass at the right of the insulation tape and we found that plasma is only generated there at above 3 kV. I am planning to use a 10 kV nanosecond pulsed HV generator SOI am thinking that this reactor may not work. Is there any way for me to rectify or isolate this? I am also thinking of the EM waves leakage at high frequency.

Comment: Look up the Paschen curve for Ar. Use a good clean insulator to feed the gas, long enough that the field strength is low enough not to break down the Ar at the feed pressure.

Comment: Hi do you mean to change the inlet gas tubing to a long and insulated one?

Answer (score 0):

Make the electrode close to the outlet between 5 and 8 mm the air will ionize, and the added gas is for cooling. the pipe around the electrode needs to be non-conductive.

Use a pointed electrode.

It is possible to put a close to the outlet moveable grounded ring, this gives the option for adjustment.